# Finding the most consecutive sequence of any item of a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

How can I find the most consecutive sequence of any item(integers) of a list in Python?

```
my_list = [1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 1, 5, 5]
```

I want to extract `[5, 5, 5, 5]` from the list.

N.B. Please, correct me if I've written anything wrong. :-)

Comment: `my_list[5:9]` N.B. Please: This is a joke.

Comment: @np.array What if you don't know the indexes? What if you need to do it dynamically like? N.B. You've got a great brain!!!

Comment: @CarlesMitjans, JunaidHira: You don't even know what Jokes mean don't you?

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple equally "longest" subsequences, i.e. `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby()` and `max()`:

```
In [1]: my_list = [1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 1, 5, 5]

In [2]: from itertools import groupby

In [4]: max([list(g) for _, g in groupby(my_list)], key=len)
Out[4]: [5, 5, 5, 5]
```